# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade to 15.04

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel, 15.04

I had ubuntu 14.04. tried upgrading to 15.04. all the files were downloaded and the upgrade process was started. some error messages showed up during installation but the upgrade process was finished. after that I tried restarting my computer, but clicking on restart or shutdown buttons didn't worked for me, so I turned off the computer by holding down the power button. but after turning it on again It didn't boot up and showed me the "Kernel Panic" problem.
I tried booting up ubuntu in recovery mode with GRUB menu, but again the "kernel panic" problem.

As I'm posting this question, I'm using the ubuntu 14.04 live CD.
I found that I can reinstall ubuntu without losing my files, but because I had upgraded to ubuntu 15.04, I can't use this option. it only allows me to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside ubuntu 15.04. if I do this, will I be able to access my old files and documents?

I currently managed to copy my `/var/www` folder from my internal `996 GB volume` to my `external hard drive`, but it doesn't allow me to copy my documents, music, pictures which are stored in my `/home` directory. it says I have no permission.
can I use terminal to change the permission of the folders in `/home` and copy them?

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: no, it's not. @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: What are the current permissions?  What is the output of `ls -l /home/`?

Comment: try to `sudo cp -r /mnt/home/agha /home/agha` or change the permissions:  `sudo chmod -R a+w a+r /mnt/home/agha`(I currently do not know, if `a+w` is needed)

Comment: or you could just to `chroot` into the `15.04` and fix the kernel. see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method for copying your data would be to open up terminal type in:

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then just copy the data to your external hardrive. I usually do it that way when I have to reinstall my Ubuntu installation.

Also don't worry about permissions, they should be alright once your system is reinstalled, if not, post a comment bellow and I'll tell you how to fix them.